# How to check form data if it has the correct answers

Tags: php, jquery, forms

So i've got this:

Index.php:

```
<?php
include "phpscripts/databaseconn.php";
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'lidl');
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Query we are going to use on the index page
$sql = "SELECT * FROM producten ORDER BY Rand()";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '  <tr>
                    <td><img src="'.$row['Afb'].'"></td>
                    <td>'.$row['Naam'].'</td>
                    <td><input class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="'.$row['Naamlower'].'" placeholder="..."></td>
                </tr>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
// Shut down connection with DB
$conn->close();
?>
```

A table within a form is created, based on data that the website gets from a database.

Example:
[image: Image of fruit, name of fruit, input]

As soon as the user clicks on "Verzenden" there has to be a check, if what they filled in at the input, is the same as the PLU code. The plu code is in the database, connected to the products.

[image: Example from the database]

If the filled in answer, is not the same as the plu code (Example from first image: Someone filled in input '50', the check has to be incorrect, because the PLU code is '30'according to the database), the background color of that input field should be changed to red.

I've tried a couple of things, but it didnt work. I hope someone here is able to table on how i should do that. You don't have to type the code for me, just tell me how to do it and i'll figure it out!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Am i allowed to bump?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your loop code replacing the last td element:

```
echo '<td>
    <input class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="'.$row['Naamlower'].'" placeholder="..." onchange="validatePLU(this, \''.$row['Naamlower'].'\')">
    <input type="hidden" id="'.$row['Naamlower'].'_plu" value="'.$row['PLU'].'">
</td>';
```

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function validatePLU(input, name)
{
    var plu_actual = parseInt(document.getElementById(name+'_plu').value);
    var plu_input = parseInt(input.value);

    if(plu_actual != plug_input)
    {
        input.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
    }
    else
    {
        input.style.backgroundColor = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything unfortunatly and doesnt come up with any errors whatsoever. But i like the idea of adding a hidden input field with the answers :D

EDIT: Found out that every time i press Submit, the order of the table gets changed aswell. The order should only change on page refresh and if you click on 'opnieuw'